# I need help creating a data dictionary for PHP/MySQL driven application

Tags: php, mysql, properties, data-dictionary

I am creating a property search/ comparison website. I require help creating the mysql tables that house the data.

I am unsure how many tables I will need and what I should use for the column headings also.

I want the website to be as precise and complete as possible.

I got the idea to create this website as I am currently looking for a place to live and the search criteria is really simple however the property comparison websites don't have complete/accurate data on the properties of which I'm searching.

I don't know how 'normalised' the tables need to be, for example I could have:

TABLE: properties, FIELDS: id, address_id, bedrooms, bathrooms, garage, garden.
TABLE: address, FIELDS: address_id, address_line_1, address_line_2, address_line_3, town, city, postcode.

But then would I need to go into detail about each bedroom within a house and specify its dimensions etc.

If anyone has any suggestions, no matter how small. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It would be beneficial to put longitude and latitude in as well. This would make it easier to calculate distance. If someone for example wanted a property in ab1 1ba you could show property within this postcode as well as property within x amount of miles.

Comment: Suggestion: if you don't know what your app should do, you can't know how to design the database. First think about what your app should do. Then, from a purely commercial point of view: even if your app is *able* to show all the dimensions of all the bedrooms of all the properties, who will enter all this information in the database? Where will you find this information?

Comment: @JB Nizet the people who are listing/selling/letting the property will be required to enter all of the information, for example. If I was going to add a new property to the database and I said it was a house with two bedroom and one bathroom. I would be required to enter some information about the two bedrooms and the bathroom like the dimensions, a photo of each room etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arbitrary properties of the house you could have one table for all.

```
CREATE TABLE `property_prop` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`properties_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`name` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
`value` VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) ,
INDEX ( `property_id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM

INSERT INTO property_prop (properties_id,name,value) VALUES (100,'Spacing','100');
INSERT INTO property_prop (properties_id,name,value) VALUES (100,'Rooms','4');
INSERT INTO property_prop (properties_id,name,value) VALUES (100,'Description','This is a nice house. ;)');

//Get a list of all properties for house with id 100.
SELECT name,value FROM property_prop WHERE properties_id=100;
```

Comment: How could I select a property from the properties table with number of bedrooms = 3 and then select all of the arbitrary information? Would this need a mysql_join function?

Comment: @Mike To get the list of the houses you look for you could use: `SELECT id FROM property_prop WHERE name='bedrooms' AND value='3'`. Loop through the results and query: `SELECT name,value FROM property_prop WHERE id=$the_id`

Answer (score 0):

For good and fast searching on site the best way is standalone searching server like SOLR or Sphinx. Regarding your question:

Mysql Solution.

1. Create table like you described.
2. Storing data in xml format for each field. For example, for field bathrooms you can create xml like

   <rooms number="3">
       <room length="5" width="10">
       <room length="7" width="9">
   <rooms>
3. Access to specific value in some field via mysql function ExtractValue(). See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html